# Jordan form of the matrices of a group

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let's consider a set of $m$ generic square matricies $(N;N) $ defined on $R$ which forms a group. Chosen one of these $ m $ matrices, I know that, by changing the base on my vectorial space, I can obtain a diagonal matrix or at least a matrix in a Jordan form. My question is, does exist a particular change of basis rapresented by the matrix $T$, which diagonalizes or puts in Jordan form **all the matrices** of the group? If so, how is this matrix $T$?

Comment: I think at least the group should be Abelian.